# Launch OpenCV window from CLion

Tags: c++, opencv, clion

I want my application to create a window that will show my camera feed.  my code is correct in regards to a vanilla implementation,

```
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
cv::VideoCapture cap(0);
const cv::String windowName = "helloThere";
cv::Mat frame;
    while(1)
    {
        cap >> frame;
        if(frame.empty()) // Check for invalid input
        {
            std::cout << "Could not open or find the frame" << std::endl;
            return -1;
        }
    imshow(windowName, frame);
    std::cout << frame << std::endl;

    }
    return 0;
}
```

but I think that, because I am launching from CLion, the window object isn't launching properly.  I am able to log output from the frame, so my question is:
Does anyone know how to get a namedWindow to launch from a CLion runtime? sort of a newb question, but I think helpful for posterity. I haven't seen anything about this

Comment: You are using `String` rather than a `char*` for the window name. Try `imshow(windowName.c_str(), frame);`

Comment: That didn't work. Also notice that I'm running through the cv namespace intentionally.  At any rate, this didn't change the behavior. I am certain it has to do with the launch space in some capacity because the same code will launch just fine from cli

Comment: Ahh, I've got it now. You have to call `waitKey()` after `imshow()` to allow the screen redrawing to take place.

Comment: nah that did work either,  I think it works within a while loop as well. regardless, the window didnt launch from the clion version

Comment: Please update your code in the question to your latest and greatest version. Also, does it run if you start it from the command line outside CLion?